# Swift dictionary short-hand declaration error

Tags: swift

Why is it a compilation error if I write:

```
let d = [String: AnyObject!]() // error: Operand postfix "!" should have an optional type
```

but not an error if I write:

```
let d = Dictionary<String, AnyObject!>() // ok
```

Comment: Very good question, should behave the same. Apparently the compiler thinks that you want to unwrap `AnyObject` because maybe it's within brackets? Must be a bug i suppose

Comment: Note that `let d:[String: AnyObject!] = [:]` works.

Comment: Also note that let d = [String: AnyObject?] works...